# override postLogin in AuthController with new fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have overridden the postLogin to check attempt method on user status in addition username and password

my updated code is:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password', 'status' = 1);

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'username' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
                ]);
}
```

but does not work the user status is 0 and he can login.

where is my fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing wrong. If you want to add additional check to login process, you don't need to override `postLogin()`

Instead, you need to add [middleware](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style) which will check status *after* request:

1. `artisan make:middleware UserStatusMiddleware`
2. Edit middleware to check status after request:

```php
class UserStatusMiddleware {

    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $this->auth->getUser();

        if ($user->status === 1) {
            return Redirect::to('home');

        } else {
            $this->auth->logout(); 
            return Redirect::to('auth/login');
        }
    }
}
```

3. Activate middleware by adding it to `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'status' => 'App\Http\Middleware\UserStatusMiddleware',
];
```

4. Add middleware to your route:

```php
$router->post("/auth/login", "Auth\AuthController@postLogin", ['middleware' => 'status']);
```

Comment: I am newbie, could you please tell me where can i inject this middleware?

Comment: I created new middleware as u said and updated the code. Now 'check status after request' where will I inject this middleware?

Comment: in ``app/Http/Kernel.php`` add your middleware to ``$middleware`` array, I added this step to answer.

Comment: got this error: Class App\Http\Middleware\Guard does not exist

Comment: add ``use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;`` to ``UserStatusMiddleware.php``

Comment: ok, works,   but my question now is: this middleware will check in every request rigth? so if i need it in specific route i need to add it in route array in kernel right?

Comment: you're right, please take a look at updated answer (steps 3 and 4).

Comment: it seems there is a missing step because i can logging with that user that has status = 0;

Comment: show me the middleware code you're using instead of comments in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73572/discussion-between-ayman-hussein-and-limonte).

Comment: If you want to redirect a user back to the login screen as a failure then you need to call `$this->auth->logout();` before the redirect.

Comment: @limonte That last return will never get hit. The best thing would be to remove it and move the contents of else out. This adds a performance boost as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
if(empty($credentials['status'])){
   $credentials['status'] = 1;
}
```